# 'ReporteRs' Landscape Layout

Tags: r, reporters

When using the ReporteRs package, I would like to create a document entirely in landscape. When i try to do this using the addSection(doc, landscape = TRUE) function, the first page is outputting as a blank portrait page. How can I avoid this happening?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This can't be avoid as it create a new section and if `horizontal=TRUE`, it needs a new page.

In your case, best would be to use a template with a landscape layout.

```
doc <- docx(template = "my_horizontal_template.docx")
```

Comment: David, can `ReporteRs` turn the following into a `.docx` file: `par(mfcol = c(7, 4), mar = rep(.1, 4), oma = rep(7, 4))  ;

invisible(lapply(1:28, plot, t = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n"))`